# onClick is not consistency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have an issue about event in React. Link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-9jo6t?file=/index.js).
Here is my index.js file.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setX(false), 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      onClick={
        x
          ? () => {
              console.log("Clicked");
            }
          : undefined
      }
    >
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

After the useEffect is run, onClick is set to `undefined`.

**Expected:**
No **click** event is attached to the div

**Actual:**
There is an noop function, generated from React DOM, is attached to the div.

Comment: React events are not put onto the html event attributes like `onclick`, ie it wont look like `<div onclick="...">` IIRC React use a global delegated event handler set on window/document set through `addEventListener`

Comment: So, at least I can see where my console.log statement is?

Comment: You can see the console.log in your code. Why would you need to see it in the inspector?

Comment: I need do some stuff about accessibility. If I remove `!` in ternary operator, the click event become noop function of React DOM. It must be `undefined`, isn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-zhqne?file=/index.js:0-370)

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(true);
  
  const toggle = () => { 
    setX (!x);
    console.log(x ? "clicked": "undefined");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={toggle}>Hello World</div>
      <div>{x ? "Im closed" : "Im open"}</div>
    </div>
         );
     }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: It is still same. I need set onClick is undefined, not noop function or anything when certain condition is meet.

Comment: I know it is the same.. can you please try once and check it out please.

Comment: I checked and updated the post. Did you produce that behaviour ?

Comment: Does giving a negative solve your problem? Ok..  I didn't understand what you wanted to make using the useEffect? I understand that you want to toggle your state but again what are you trying to do console logging for clicked or undefined. I have edited my answer. Let me know if it solved your problem or if you are facing any problem on using it.

Comment: I try removing useEffect and found that the problem is belong to React. When we declare onClick with certain function, and after that, we set it to undefined. Then, it is not completely undefined, React just set it to dummy function like () => {}. What I want is no any event is attached to this element at all.

Comment: U mean instead of x ? Function : undefined you want it to be like   x && Function. Which does the same thing. Did you get to know the answer what u were looking for?

Comment: Setting it to undefined is not good practice. the syntax is like this x ? True - do something : false - do something OR u can do it like so..  x && true - do something. In the place of true u put ur function which executes if x is true. U can refer ternary operators to learn about it.  Did you get to know the answer what u were looking for if it did please mark ur answer.